# MySQL Distinct Records With Count

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a photos table, with two columns in that table named "id" and "user_id".  Obviously one user can have many photos.  I'd like to run a query that can give me the photo count for each user.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

```
select user_id, count(*) as photo_count from photos group by user_id
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
SELECT t.user_id,
       COUNT(*) AS photo_count
  FROM PHOTOS
GROUP BY t.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

use count as your aggregate function and groupby clause to give the count of specific attribute,

here is the sample:

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) 'Photos Count'
from photos
group by user_id
```